# how to map the one of two tables in dataset to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview, dataset, sqldataadapter

I'm extracting data using a single MS SQL stored procedure using two select queries

```
SELECT        setup_description, setup_name FROM Setup WHERE (setup_name = @setup_name)
SELECT        vm_name, depends_on_vm_name, setup_name FROM Setup_Vm WHERE      (setup_name = @setup_name)
```

Then in the 'Data Access' layer I get data into dataset as below,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setup_name", setupName);
con.Open();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
  ds = new DataSet();                                                
  da.Fill(ds, "SetupDetails");
  return ds;
}
```

Then I want to get data in both tables to a text box and Datagrid view.

I can get the data to the text box and datagrid view as below,

```
//fill text box
txtSetupDescription.Text = dsSetupDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0 ["setup_description"].ToString();

//fill datagridview
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView.DataSource = dsSetupDetails;
dataGridView.DataMember = "SetupDetails;
```

I got data to the textbox successfully. But I unable to get data to data grid view.

Comment: Is this a Web app or Windows app? Also, have you checked if you are getting "SetupDetails" name in your DataSet as return? Usually it returns as Table1, Table2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the data source via

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dsSetupDetails.Tables[0];
```

and then binding it

```
dataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Actually I didn't..  but I managed to solve in another way...thanks a lot